# 2D Char Array Memory Error

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I'm having problems displaying a 2d char array.

Below is the functions which generates the data which the function below that will be using. it takes an input and creates a 2d char array of the tokens. From observing in VS2012 this works correctly.

Cheers

Comment: Very relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to chris' comment (Refer to: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)) , I feel to make your program work, you need to reconsider the allocation of `tokens` in `TokStr` function.

You could modify this declaration `char *tokens[10];` to following piece of code. With this change, your code should work fine.

```
char **tokens;
tokens = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
```